# Codename one parsing

Tags: java, json, codenameone

i'm struggling with a simple method that should give me back an object but using the parse (`connectionRequest` , `readresponse` and `postresponse`) it always gives me nullable value.

Example of my code

```
Paiement P = new PaiementDAO().FindByCardNumber("5300721124642197");
System.out.println("hi "+P.getCardHolderName());
```

the output is always executing the `system.out.println` first then entering the `findby` method what's wrong ?

this is my full code

```
    `       public Paiement FindByCardNumber(String CardNumber) {
Paiement P = new Paiement();
        ConnectionRequest connectionRequest;
        connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {
            List<Paiement> colors = new ArrayList<>();

            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("hi read response");
                JSONParser json = new JSONParser();
                try {
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");

                    Map<String, Object> data = json.parseJSON(reader);

                    List<Map<String, Object>> content
                            = (List<Map<String, Object>>) data.get("root");
                    colors.clear();
                    for (Map<String, Object> obj : content) {
                        colors.add(
                                new Paiement((String) obj.get("cardholdername"), (String) obj.get("cardnumber"), (String) obj.get("expirationdate"), (String) obj.get("securitycode"), (String) obj.get("type"), Float.parseFloat((String) obj.get("solde"))));
                    }
                } catch (IOException err) {
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void postResponse() {
                System.out.println("hi post response");

                for (Paiement x : colors) {
                    P = x;
                    System.out.println(P);
    return;
                }
            }

        };enter code here
        connectionRequest.setUrl("http://localhost/payement/findbynumber.php?num=" + CardNumber);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(connectionRequest);
    return P;`
```

Comment: Never catch an exception like that. It is very possible you are swallowing an error with no logging. I suggest placing a breakpoint on the first line of the response and stepping over the code. Do you get the values back? It's very unclear what's the problem but you can easily see it by inspecting the variables,

Comment: if i add some (system.out.println) i get the wanted value but the problem is that when this code is executed, first thing to be executed is those line : 
{connectionRequest.setUrl("http://localhost/payement/findbynumber.php?num=" + CardNumber);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(connectionRequest);
    return P;`}

Comment: OK, your question wasn't clear on that. `addToQueue` is asynchronous. You can replace it with `addToQueueAndWait()`.

Comment: thank you "Shai Almog" it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are missing this line?

```
connectionRequest.setPost(false);
```

I'm not sure, but I think it's set to true by default.

Comment: It might not have solved the issue but @Carlos is correct... You have a get request.

Answer (score 1):

If your execution order assumption is right -- `DAO.FindByCardNumber` might return lazy object or future instead of found one and real `findby` executes at moment of `P` access or in different thread.

To confirm that you should call `P.getCardHolderName()` before `System.out.println` and trace real execution order (is `P` fields initialized at `DAO.FindBy*` or at `P.getCardHolderName()`?).

**UPDATE:**

Yes, your DAO is asynchronous and real find executes in parallel with main thread. So `System.out.println` starts early and have to wait DAO request completion.

Comment: Yes i've initialized P at DAO.findBy but it always keep running that way it execute System.out.println() then it execute DAO.findBy i will show you my code :

Comment: public Paiement FindByCardNumber(String CardNumber) {
Paiement P = new Paiement();
        ConnectionRequest connectionRequest;
        connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {
            List<Paiement> colors = new ArrayList<>();

            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("hi read response");
                JSONParser json = new JSONParser();
                try {
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");

Comment: Map<String, Object> data = json.parseJSON(reader);
                    List<Map<String, Object>> content
                            = (List<Map<String, Object>>) data.get("root");
                    colors.clear();
                    for (Map<String, Object> obj : content) {
                        colors.add(
                                new Paiement((String) obj.get("cardholdername"), (String) obj.get("cardnumber"), (String) obj.get("expirationdate"), (String) obj.get("securitycode"), (String) obj.get("type"), Float.parseFloat((String) obj.get("solde"))));
                    }

Comment: } catch (IOException err) {

                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void postResponse() {
                System.out.println("hi post response");

                for (Paiement x : colors) {
                    P = x;
                    System.out.println(P);
                }
            } };
        connectionRequest.setUrl("http://localhost/payement/findbynumber.php?num=" + CardNumber);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(connectionRequest);
 return P;
    }

Comment: how to i'm really newbee at stackoverflow

Comment: Click "edit" button above the question text (behind tags).

Comment: Yes, your DAO is async and none is wrong. It should work as you described in question.

Comment: so what should i do... i'm really struggling with it from two days ago

Comment: If code is working property -- nothing. If you really want to do this operation synchronous (why?) -- call some method of `P` (like `get`) or use appropriate method in `DAO` (sync get). I think, you should ask author of `DAO` about usage patterns he mentioned during development.